# Flutter | Screen turn black color background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toggle_switch/toggle_switch.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:mybmiapp/calculatedval.dart';
import 'package:mybmiapp/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyState createState() => _MyState();
}
class _MyState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;
  var msgController = TextEditingController();
  var msgController2 = TextEditingController();
  int genderindex = 0;
  String text3 = "";
  int maxLength = 10;
  String kg = "0";
  String p = "32";
  double? n = null;
  double? n2 = null;
  double oldVal = 0.00;
  double newVal = 0.00;
  double oldVal2 = 0.00;
  double newVal2 = 0.00;
  @override
  final heightcon = TextEditingController();
  final weightcon = TextEditingController();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
        home: Center(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 50),
                Material(
                  elevation: 30.0,
                  shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: 300,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: heightcon,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'textfield',
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 2.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              width: 2.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (heightval) {  },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50),
                Material(
                  elevation: 30.0,
                  shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: weightcon,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'textfield',
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 2.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              width: 2.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (weightval) {  },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 57,
                  width: 150,
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 30,
                    shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 23,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                      child: Text('button'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print(genderindex);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ));
    //   ],
    //);
  }
}
```

Next Screen (calculatedval.dart) code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mybmiapp/globals.dart' as globals;
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text((globals.weightvalue).toStringAsFixed(2)),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Material(
              elevation: 30,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 75,
                  width: 245,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "BMI IS " + (globals.bmi).toStringAsFixed(2),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 33,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Material(
              elevation: 30,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 80,
                  width: 245,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "BMI Level is " + globals.BmiLevel,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 33,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            Text("only for 20 years plus")
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my screen output.

[image: my app screen]

My console output

W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3079): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3079): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
2
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3079): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 3079): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

Comment: Use `scaffold` widget as a `child` of `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Scaffold` or `Material` widget wrap your code and don't need to use `MaterialApp` I have updated the code little bit take a look

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      runApp(MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(),
        home: MyApp(),
      ));
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyState createState() => _MyState();
    }

    class _MyState extends State<MyApp> {
      bool _isBannerAdReady = false;
      var msgController = TextEditingController();
      var msgController2 = TextEditingController();
      int genderindex = 0;
      String text3 = "";
      int maxLength = 10;
      String kg = "0";
      String p = "32";
      double? n = null;
      double? n2 = null;
      double oldVal = 0.00;
      double newVal = 0.00;
      double oldVal2 = 0.00;
      double newVal2 = 0.00;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final heightcon = TextEditingController();
        final weightcon = TextEditingController();
        return Material(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            Material(
              elevation: 30.0,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 300,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: heightcon,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'textfield',
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (heightval) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            Material(
              elevation: 30.0,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: weightcon,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'textfield',
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (weightval) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            SizedBox(
              height: 57,
              width: 150,
              child: Material(
                elevation: 30,
                shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 23,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                  child: Text('button'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print(genderindex);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        );
        //);
      }
    }

    class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('(globals.weightvalue).toStringAsFixed(2)'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Material(
              elevation: 30,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 75,
                  width: 245,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "BMI IS " + ' (globals.bmi).toStringAsFixed(2)',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 33,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Material(
              elevation: 30,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 80,
                  width: 245,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "BMI Level is " + 'globals.BmiLevel',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 33,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            Text("only for 20 years plus")
          ])),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me .By the way I just  starts learn flutter this month.